# What is a single word to describe the state of being singular or plural?

Tags: single-word-requests

In grammar we have singular and plural nouns. Is there one word to describe this component, like we have the word "tense" to describe the state of being "past", "present", or "future?"
e.g.,

> Whether the verb should be singular or plural depends on its *[word-goes-here].*

Comment: We typically use 'number' for the contrast of singular vs plural.

Comment: Whether the verb should be singular or plural depends on the subject's number, not its.

Comment: Note that there are non-count usages. Also, nouns may be singular in form but take a plural verb-form mandatorily (poultry, cattle) or optionally (team, committee). They may be plural form, but take a singular verb-form mandatorily (news, measles) or optionally (headquarters). Again, non-countness does not necessarily correspond to non-countability of referent (furniture: 3 tables and 12 chairs; cattle: 24 cows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Number

See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number), for example.

For example, a linguist might say that the verbs in a language "agree in number" with their subjects.